# Operations on ListView with an adapter

Tags: android, listview

I have an Activity with a ListView and an adapter. Each row in my ListView contains one EditText and one CheckBox. I have two problems with this ListView:
first: what is the best way to save checked checkboxes after changing device orientation or pressing home button?
second: I implemented functionality to delete selected rows. When I click on checkbox and press a "delete button" the I call notifyDataSetChanged on my Adapter and everything is ok but if selected row isn't last row on my list then after all operations first field after deleted field becomes checked. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The listview is recycling the views all the time. That means that the checkbox in the field after the deleted field is the SAME checkbox as was in the deleted field. That is why it becomes checked.

The solution is for the checked state to always be stored outside the view, in the activity. The easiest way is probably a Map of some key to a Boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Create Model fro list item and store checked and unchecked value to one variable and also you have to use getTag() and setTag() method.